# Crop array values with min+max index given into a target array with a desired min+max index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

I've been having trouble with this for a while, so I thought I'd ask here. Basically, I need to 'crop' array values with a min and max index given into some target array, with a desired min and max index (the min and max index revolve around 0), and array sizes respect the differences between min and max. The actual array starts from index 0, of course, but the offset to real data might be different.

I've had a go at it (see below), but I'm having some difficulty. My math is really poor. The code is arranged as a JUnit test for easy running, and also so you can see what the expected results are. I don't think the mechanism in the algorithm of differentiating between area differences is a good one -- there must be a more general solution, where the same line can be used for all cases. Something like that.

This isn't homework or anything like that, it's for cropping of a grid of objects, so that I can shrink and enlarge the grid dynamically. This is just step 1.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Hmm {

    @Test
    public void shrinkTest1() {
        int[] res = arrMod(new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -1, 2);
        int[] exp =  new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void expandTest1() {
        int[] res = arrMod(new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 4);
        int[] exp = new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void expandTest2() {
        int[] res = arrMod(new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 6);
        int[] exp = new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }   

    @Test
    public void sameTest1() {
        int[] res = arrMod(new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 2);
        int[] exp = new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }   

    public int[] arrMod(int[] data, int min, int max, int newmin, int newmax) {
        int minDiff = newmin - min;
        int maxDiff = newmax - max;

        System.out.println("minDiff: " + minDiff + ", maxDiff: " + maxDiff);

        int[] newdata = new int[newmax - newmin + 1];

        if ((newmax - newmin) > (max - min)) {
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, newdata, maxDiff, max - min + 1);
        } else if ((newmax - newmin) < (max - min)) {   
            System.arraycopy(data, minDiff, newdata, 0, newmax - newmin + 1);
        } else {
            // ...
        }

        return newdata;
    }
```

Edit: I've got it working with the following code, but are there any merging improvements between the sub-cases which can be made to make the code smaller? I don't like the look of them. Also, I'm using Object[], but feel free to turn it back to int[] for testing if it doesn't work with Integer[].

```
public static final <T> T[] arrMod(T[] data, int min, int max, int newmin, int newmax) {
    //System.out.println(
    //  "arrMod(data=" + Arrays.toString(data) + ",min=" + min + ",max=" + max +
    //  ",newmin=" + newmin + ",newmax=" + newmax + ")"
    //);

    int minDiff = newmin - min;
    int maxDiff = newmax - max;

    //System.out.println("minDiff: " + minDiff + ", maxDiff: " + maxDiff);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] newdata = (T[])Array.newInstance(data.getClass().getComponentType(), newmax - newmin + 1);
    System.out.println("newdata: " + newdata);

    if ((maxDiff - minDiff) > 0) {
        // grow
        //System.out.println("expand: (maxDiff - minDiff) > 0");
        arraycopy(data, 0, newdata, -minDiff, max - min + 1);
    } else if ((maxDiff - minDiff) < 0) {
        // shrink
        //System.out.println("shrink: (maxDiff - minDiff) < 0");
        arraycopy(data, minDiff, newdata, 0, newmax - newmin + 1);
    } else {
        // move
        //System.out.println("same: (maxDiff - minDiff) == 0");
        if (min > newmin) {     
            arraycopy(data, 0, newdata, -minDiff, max - min + maxDiff + 1);
        } else {
            arraycopy(data, maxDiff, newdata, 0, max - min - maxDiff + 1);
        }
    }

    return newdata;
}
```

Edit 2: Improved testcases:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Hmm {

    @Test
    public void shrinkTest1() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= SHRINK TEST 1 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -1, 2);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void shrinkTest2() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= SHRINK TEST 2 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, -5, 4, -1, 2);
        Integer[] exp =  new Integer[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void expandTest1() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= EXPAND TEST 1 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 4);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, null };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void expandTest2() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= EXPAND TEST 2 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 6);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, null, null, null };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }   

    @Test
    public void sameTest1() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= SAME TEST 1 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -3, 2);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void sameTest2() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= SAME TEST 2 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -1, 4);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, null };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void sameTest3() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======= SAME TEST 3 ========");
        Integer[] res = WFMap.arrMod(new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, -2, 3, -4, 1);
        Integer[] exp = new Integer[] { null, null, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        assertArrayEquals("Array " + Arrays.toString(res) + " not equal to expected " + Arrays.toString(exp), exp, res);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following lines

```
if ((newmax - newmin) > (max - min)) {
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newdata, maxDiff, max - min + 1);
}
```

indicate that the target destination is determined using the `max` values while it should be done by the `min` values (starting index is always `min`).

You have to consider two cases. If the new min is smaller than the old one you can copy the data from start and shift it somewhat to the right. Otherwise you have to remove some values from the start, i.e. copy from an index larger than zero.

```
if (minDiff < 0) {
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newdata, -minDiff, max - min + 1);
} else {
    System.arraycopy(data, minDiff, newdata, 0, max - min + 1);
}
```

Please note that this code might need some more checks on overflow depending on your use cases (e.g. for large values of `minDiff` you might run out of the source/target array bounds).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help :) Your enlargement code worked in all cases, but not shrinking code, and guessing movement code with no size change was a bit tricky (although you'd think that would be the easiest case to deal with.. strange). However, do you have any ideas for optimisation?

Comment: [System.arraycopy javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)